# How to handle a user that consistently gives bad advice?

Tags: discussion

There's a user (Prem Patel) who has answered several questions very poorly.  The main issue is that they seem to be giving CiviCRM-specific but incorrect advice - for instance, to check ConfigAndLog for a JavaScript-related issue.  Aside from that, the writing is poor.  I'm worried it's doing more harm than good - but also this person clearly knows SOMETHING about CiviCRM, if possible I'd like them to be a functional member of the SE CiviCRM community.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

If an answer is incorrect, I would suggest leaving a comment clearly specifying what is wrong.  If this is done politely and constructively it shouldn't be off-putting to the user and hopefully they will improve in future and continue to contribute to this site.

If the answer is really bad then it should be voted down so that other people know that it is wrong.

If the answer is correct but badly worded then I suggest that we help by editing the answer.